# Dynamic Table Quantity update Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to update my quantity inside a table where list of rows are there. But i want to get the specific row with the quantity.

```
 <td class="qty">
   <div class="quantity-spinner">
      <input type="number" name="product"  class="prod_qty" value="{{$food->quantity}}" data-id="{{$food->id}}" />     
   </div>
 </td>
```

// This is inside a loop so multiple row can be created.

javascript i have used :

```
$(":input").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
   var qty = $('.prod_qty').val()
   var food_id =  $('.prod_qty').attr("data-id")
});
```

But the problem is I got always first row food_id & qty not the specific one i wanted to update. How can i that specific row value?

Comment: Note that `bind` is deprecated and should be replaced with `on`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well take the value of the *current* element:

```
$(":input").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
   var qty = $(this).val()
   var food_id =  $(this).attr("data-id")
});
```